# Is the controller before_action :set_x method needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

If I use the Rails scaffold generator for the Article resource it will create a before filter and a private method like this

```
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
private
  def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Now I understand this makes your controller DRY because instead of adding `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` 4 times which is 4 lines of code, you can use the above and you save yourself... well it's still 4 lines and a similar number of keystrokes. But if you want to modify it you only have to do it in one place. But you sacrifice clarity because to see that @article is defined in those 4 actions you have to look at the before filter at the top, then at the private method at the bottom, then back at the action. For me personally this is no benefit so I always just put this in the four actions. My question is, is this merely a personal preference issue or is there a compelling reason to always use the DRY method that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the logic of retrieving gets a bit more complicated than just one line it is quite helpful, but not by any means necessary. You could also leave the `set_article` method as it is, remove the `before_action` and call it explicitly in the actions that need it, a bit of a trade off between `before_action` and repeating it in all actions. That's quite handy when the logic is a few lines of code instead of just one.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't breaking some cardinal rule when I don't use it. Thanks.